# Strange result of making one picture from to on PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, gdlib, gd2

In my project, I need to merge two pictures.

The first (img.png):

[img http://uoops.ru/1/img.png](http://uoops.ru/1/img.png)

And (for example) second (photo.png):

[img http://uoops.ru/1/photo.png](http://uoops.ru/1/photo.png)

This is PHP code:

```
$photoImage = ImageCreateFromPNG("img.png");
ImageAlphaBlending($photoImage, true);

$logoImage = ImageCreateFromPNG("photo.png");
$logoW = ImageSX($logoImage);
$logoH = ImageSY($logoImage);
ImageCopy($photoImage, $logoImage, 1, 1, 0, 0, $logoW, $logoH);

ImagePNG($photoImage, "mrkr.png", 0);
```

As result I want to have this:

http://uoops.ru/1/result.png

But I have this:

http://uoops.ru/1/mrkr.png

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you set one of the images position to be fixed. that would give the same result, except that it won't be merged, but one img over the other

Comment: hmmm....what do you mean - "set one of the images position to be fixed" Can you give a little example? ;)

Comment: @ahmad, while I might not agree with that particular method, it does bring an interesting point: what if you had the marker image be the background image of the other using CSS?

Comment: I can't use css, because i need to save it as image and use it as marker on a google map, that shows current user location (something like at foursquare.com, when you are open a map, you can see locations of your friends on a map - it's look like a marker with user photo).

Comment: Ok, then that explains why you were focusing primarily on PHP. I'll be honest; while I'm not bad at PHP, I'm unfamiliar with image processing in PHP. Best of luck, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$photoImage = ImageCreateFromPNG("img.png");

$w = imagesx($photoImage);
$h = imagesy($photoImage);
$out = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
ImageAlphaBlending($out, true);
imagefill($out, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($out, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagesavealpha($out, true);

ImageCopy($out, $photoImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);

$logoImage = ImageCreateFromPNG("photo.png");
$logoW = ImageSX($logoImage);
$logoH = ImageSY($logoImage);
ImageCopy($out, $logoImage, 1, 1, 0, 0, $logoW, $logoH);
ImagePNG($out, "mrkr.png", 0);
```

this is not really optimized but should work